# ruby, finding largest size of sub array in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, ruby

Say I have a 2D array

```
arraylist = [ [1,2,3], [78], [101,1,2,91] ]
```

How do I use the `max_by` method to find the index of the sub array that stores the most number of integers?

Answer (score 3):

```
arraylist.each_index.max_by { |i| arraylist[i].size }
  #=> 2
```

If you want the indices of all largest arrays (in case fhere's a tie) you could write the following.

```
arraylist = [ [1,2,3,4], [78], [101,1,2,91] ]
mx_size = arraylist.map(&:size).max
  #=> 4
arraylist.each_index.select { |i| arraylist[i].size == mx_size }
  #=> [0, 2]
```

Comment: This answer is the best one here so far, since it does not require redundant lookup.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
arraylist.index(arraylist.max_by{|x| x.length})
```

Didnt try but should work

Comment: may i ask, what does the statement above return? an int?

Comment: and does arraylist.max_by{|x| x.length} return a 1D array?

Comment: Yes the above line of code will return an integer value, in your case `2`, `arraylist.max_by{|x| x.length}` this will return the longest 1D array. Please note if there are more than one 1D arrays of the same length, then it will return the first array.

Comment: I wonder what is the problem to execute the line above in Irb/Pry and see, what it returns?

Comment: Harry, as I'm sure you know, Ruby sees all arrays as one-dimensional (an ordered list), though array elements can be arrays. It therefore can be confusing to refer to an array as "1D", as it may leave the impression that there "2D" (and higher) arrays as well. If you remove the two "1D's" in your comment above it makes perfect sense.

Comment: As a note, `max_by(&:length)` is the shorthand for `max_by { |x| x.length }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland noted, somehow i cant edit the comment now and plus i used it so the OP can understand.

Comment: Harry, you can't save edits of comments after five minutes of posting. If it does not cause confusion, you could delete the comment and repost the same comment, possibly with some changes.